# Nativescript Switch not to fire initial binding

Tags: nativescript

My view is

`<Switch checked="{{ active }}" propertyChange="onCheckChange"/>`

```
exports.onCheckChange = function(args)
{
   //Api Service call
}
```

Actually I am binding the active value by `API` call and the issue is that `onCheckChange` gets executed during the initial binding with false value, so whenever I initially set the `active==true` by api service call and load the page, the `onCheckChange`  is executed with `checked==false`, can anyone give me an idea about this please.

*Note: Beginner in Nativescript*

Comment: checked is DO-property and in NativeScript PropertyChanged is "thrown" after the DO change so that is the reason for your value to be "step behind". In this case instead of using propertyCahnge you can change the value directly through the Dependency Observable (DO) something like this.active = myApiResult;

Comment: @NickIliev i recreated the actual question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118760/nativescript-switch-prevent-change-event-firing-on-initial-binding please give me a answer with Dependency Observable

Answer (score 0):

I battled with the *checked* property a lot so I opted for two-way binding, which behaves as expected:

```
// test.xml    
<Switch [(ngModel)]="isUnicorn"></Switch>

// test.ts
isUnicorn: boolean = true;
......
if (this.isUnicorn) {
  console.log("It is a unicorn");
}
```

Note that to get two-way binding to work you need to import *NativeScriptFormsModule* in app.module.ts or applicable module for instance:

```
// app.module.ts
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
......
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    ......
  ],
  exports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    ......
  ],
  ......
```

Comment: not working inside `ng-template` ( for loop ) when used something like: `<Switch [(ngModel)]="item.active"></Switch>`

Answer (score 0):

The [two-way data-binding](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-data-binding) (described by `leoncc`) might be specific to the *Angular* NativeScript.

Here's a workaround without the two-way data binding, hopefully it will be easier to port to the *plain* NativeScript if needs be.

In the controller we can get the state of the `Switch` with a `ViewChild` query:

```
  checked = true;
  @ViewChild ('switch') private switch: ElementRef;
  switched() {
    let switch: Switch = this.switch.nativeElement;
    this.checked = switch.checked}
```

And in the template we should invoke the `switched` change handler:

```
<Switch #switch [checked]="checked" (checkedChange)="switched()" class="switch"></Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share my answer to this, as two-way data binding isn't working with a `<Switch>` for some reason, gives the error:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4694

And in my case, I had a list of items which next to each I wanted to give a `Switch` to turn on/off .. it was a part of a list ( for loop ) so I had to have some kind of data-binding for each switch on the items list.

I wrote it like so:

```
# Instead of two-way data binding which result an error
<Switch [checked]="item.checked">

# I wrote it as non binding:
<ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
  <StackLayout>
    <Switch checked="{{ item.checked }}">
  </StackLayout>
</ng-template>
```

And to answer the above question what was missing for you was also the `$event` so an example of how I used it as a list vs a single switch - I passed both `index` and `$event` to the function:

```
# html
<Switch checked="{{ item.checked }}" (checkedChange)="switched(index, $event)">

# ts
import { Switch } from "@nativescript/core";

switched(index, args: EventData) {
  let switch_item = args.object as Switch;
  this.my_items_array[index].checked = switch_item.checked;
}
```