# Nativescript Switch prevent change event firing on initial binding

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hi my template is something like the below

```
<ListView [items]="modules">
    <template let-item="item" >
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                <Switch (checkedChange)="onSwitchModule(item.id,$event)" [checked]="item.active"></Switch>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

My controller is

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._moduleService.getUserModules()
        .subscribe(
            response=>{
              this.modules = response.data;
            }
        )

}

onSwitchModule(itemId) {
   console.log(itemID); //Gets called on initial true binding on switch checked
}
```

The onSwitchModule get called everytime the page loads with item.active is true on any item, how to handle this ?

NOTE: Beginner in Nativescript

Comment: Please see [Answer to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914604/nativescript-switch-not-to-fire-initial-binding/50198438#50198438)

Answer (score 4):

What I did to overcome this is I watch for `tap` events instead of `checkedChange`:

```
<Switch (tap)="switchClicked" [checked]="item.active"></Switch>
```

and in the callback, you can get the current item from `bindingContext`:

```
function switchClicked(args) {
  const item = args.object.bindingContext.item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue: loading up settings data from an API, and having the `checked` event fire for the value I'd set from the api -- not desirable in my case. I didn't see a great way to prevent events from firing on the initial binding, so I decided to simply ignore events until I knew they were legit events from the user actually using the switch.

I did that by using a property `switchReady` to keep track of when you want to start recognizing change events. This pattern also keeps the toggle disabled until you're ready to start accepting changes. This makes use of Switch's `isEnabled` property, see [docs here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/switch#disable-switch).

Markup

```
<Switch [checked]="currentSettings.pushTurnedOn" [isEnabled]="switchReady" (checkedChange)="onPushSettingChange($event)" row="0" col="1"></Switch>
```

Component

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  currentSettings: Settings = new Settings(false)    
  switchReady: boolean = false

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentSettings()
  }

  public onPushSettingChange(args) {
    let settingSwitch = <Switch>args.object

    if (settingSwitch.isEnabled) {
      // do something with the event/change    
    } else {
      // we aren't ready to accept changes, do nothing with this change          
      return
    }
  }

  getCurrentSettings() {
    this.settingsService.loadCurrentSettings().subscribe(
      () => {
        this.currentSettings = this.settingsService.currentSettings
        // we've applied our api change via data binding, it's okay to accept switch events now
        this.switchReady = true
      },
      err => alert('There was a problem retrieving your settings.')
    )
  }
}
```